# Vowpal Wabbit command not found: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, cygwin

When I enter this command:

```
./vw -d click.train.vw -f click.model.vw --loss_function logistic
```

on cygwin I got this error:

> -bash: ./vw: No such file or directory

I actually want to implement "PREDICTING CTR WITH ONLINE MACHINE LEARNING" website link for reference :
http://mlwave.com/predicting-click-through-rates-with-online-machine-learning/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the `vw` script is in the folder where you execute the command? If you run `./command` it means that the `command` executable needs to be in the working directory.

Comment: yes fejese script in under the folder.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have executable flags? You can check it with `ls -la vw`. Check what you got for that.

Comment: If the script exists in the current directory and has the execute bit set then that means the shebang line in that script is likely pointing to a command that doesn't exist.

Comment: Got this error "ls: cannot access vw: No such file or directory" when run this command : $ ls -la vw

Answer (score 1):

*Answer based on common mistakes.*

### Execution by inexact name

#### Filename with blanks

Suppose you write [`ls`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html) in the command line and obtain the following:

```
$ ls 
anyfile  command
```

Then, you call your command with `./command` and get the following:

```
$ ./command
bash: ./command: No such file or directory
```

Here you can think [`ls`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html) is wrong, but the actuality is that you can't easily recognize if a filename have, for example, leading or trailing spaces:

```
$ ls -Q  # -Q, --quote-name -> enclose entry names in double quotes
"anyfile"  "command "
```

As you see, here my `command` has a trailing space:

```
$ ./"command "  # it works
```

#### Filename with extension

A common mistake is to call the command by the name without the extension (if any).
Let's name the command: `command.sh`:

```
$ ./command # wrong
$ ./command.sh # OK
```

---

### Wrong file [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

If you call your command with the prefix `./`, it needs to be in your current directory (`$PWD`). If it is not, you will get:

```
$ ./command # relative path -> same as "$PWD/command"
bash: ./command: No such file or directory
```

In that case, you can try the following:

#### Executing the command by its absolute path

```
$ /home/user/command # absolute path (example). It starts with a slash (/).
```

#### Let the shell locate the command

If you provide just the command name without slashes, `bash` searches in each directory of the `$PATH` variable, for an executable file named `command`.

```
$ command
```

You can do that search with the [`which`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/which1.html) command:

```
$ which command
/usr/bin/command
```

If the search fails, you'll get comething like:

```
$ which unexistent_command
which: no unexistent_command in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin)
```

---

### Broken [link](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chmod1.html)

Now, suppose you write [`ls -Q`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html) in the command line and obtain the following:

```
$ ls -Q
"anyfile"  "command"
```

This time, you can be 100% secure `command` exists but when you try to execute it:

```
$ ./command
bash: ./command: No such file or directory
```

Reason? `bash` complains `command` doesn't exist, but what doesn't exist is the file `command` is pointing to by a [Symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). e.g.:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users  0 Jan 14 02:12 anyfile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user users 27 Jan 14 02:12 command -> /usr/bin/unexistent_command

$ ls /usr/bin/unexistent_command
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/unexistent_command: No such file or directory
```

---

*Notice that the following surely throw different errors that the one you are getting...*

### Execution [permission](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php)

To execute a file, it must have the **x** bit activated. With [`ls -l`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ls1.html) you can check the file permission.

```
$ ls -l command
-rw-r--r-- 1 user users 0 Jan  3 19:52 command
```

In this case (it doesn't have the **x** bit activated), you can give permission with [`chmod`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chmod1.html):

```
$ chmod +x command
$ ls -l command
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user users 0 Jan  3 19:52 command
```